# unable to enable systemctl service

Tags: 16.04, systemd, nis

I am facing problem with login to Nis server from my host machine every time after reboot. NIS host machine is running with Ubuntu 16.04 server os.

The status of `ypbind` and `rpcbind` are as follows after reboot.

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl status rpcbind
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind portmap service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/rpcbind.service.d
           └─50-rpcbind-$portmap.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@ubuntu:~# 
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl status ypbind
● nis.service - LSB: Start NIS client and server daemons.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nis; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-12-18 12:06:41 MUT; 53s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1259 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nis start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Dec 18 12:06:35 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:36 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:37 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:38 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:39 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:40 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:41 ubuntu nis[1259]:  * ....
Dec 18 12:06:41 ubuntu nis[1259]:    ...fail!
Dec 18 12:06:41 ubuntu nis[1259]:    ...done.
Dec 18 12:06:41 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NIS client and server daemons..
```

If i start both services with `systemctl start` command it will work perfect and i will be able to login to nis server.

And if i enable these services with `systemctl enable` command in order to start at booting time, i will get the following output.

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl enable rpcbind
Synchronizing state of rpcbind.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable rpcbind
root@ubuntu:~# 
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl enable ypbind
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:~# 
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Note that even if `systemctl enable rpcbind` command ran without any error. the service is not starting while booting also i cannot enable the `ypbind` service at all.

I also tried `systemctl daemon-reload` still the same.

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ypbind` seems to be *provided* by a SysV init script (`/etc/init.d/nis`). For a SysV init script, its systemd service is automatically generated and enabled based on the contents of the script and the links in `/etc/rc*.d`. Since there's no actual `/etc/init.d/ypbind`, it seems systemd is confused:

```
$ systemctl enable ypbind
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
$ systemctl enable nis
nis.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nis
...
```

Probably a minor bug, but note that, by default it's already enabled (`vendor preset: enabled`).

Comment: Could you please tell me if there is any possible way to over come this issue ?

Comment: NIS is enabled, there's no issue there. Your problem is with rpcbind, and that's a separate problem.

Comment: But i am able to login if only i start both rpcbind and ypbind service manually. i tried stopping ypbind and starting rpcbind and i couldn't login to nis. so that means ypbind plays a role in nis host, right ?

Comment: @Rooney you're mixing two separate issues: your problem with starting rpcbind and your problem with enabling ypbind. The second is what your question is asking about, and as I answered, is not a problem. So either edit your question to focus on the first, or post a new question about that. Don't continue mixing them.

Comment: Oh okay, now its clear. I will post a new question. thanks.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. Now everything working perfect. thanks for helping.  This was the question i asked. https://askubuntu.com/questions/987390/problem-with-starting-rpcbind.