# problem with starting rpcbind

Tags: 16.04, systemd, nis

I am facing a problem with `rpcbind`. the service is not starting after the reboot even after enabling the service.

I get the following output when i run `systemctl status rpcbind` just after reboot.

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl status rpcbind
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind portmap service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/rpcbind.service.d
           └─50-rpcbind-$portmap.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@ubuntu:~#
```

And if i start the service `systemctl start rpcbind` the service will start.

And when i enable the service with `systemctl enable rpcbind` command i get the following output.

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl enable rpcbind
Synchronizing state of rpcbind.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable rpcbind
```

Output of `cat /lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service`

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service 
[Unit]
Description=RPC bind portmap service
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
Before=remote-fs-pre.target
Requires=rpcbind.socket
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Environment="OPTIONS=-w"
ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -f $OPTIONS
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/rpcbind.conf
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/rpcbind
Type=notify
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
Also=rpcbind.socket
```

But the service still not enabling after the reboot.

Can anybody help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue.

Creating a symbolic link of `rpcbind.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` directory fixed the issue.

```
ln -s '/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rpcbind.service'
```

Answer (score 0):

> the service is not starting after the reboot even after enabling the service.

It is not supposed to.  It is a socket-activated service.  It is `rpcbind.socket` that you have to enable, not `rpcbind.service`.